# Is there a way to add a path to all src attributes of image tags?

Tags: jquery, xhtml

I would like to add a path "images/" to all img tags in my html file. Is that possible and if how can I achive that?

Comment: Why? The answer might depend on what you're trying to do.

Comment: If your images paths are broken without javascript involvement it's a bug you need to fix elsewhere. Using javascript isn't solving the problem, it's adding dead weight to the page you shouldn't need.

Comment: Yes, this isn't the best way to do that... but maybe an interessant experiment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work well:

```
$("img").each( function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "images/" + $(this).attr("src"));
});
```

note that it has sense only if you have already relative path to your images.

Answer (score 1):

From what? Is search/replace in notepad good enough?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a jQuery specific way to do this, but this basic JS loop will do it. Kind of a strange thing to do after loading all the images from a different URL already though.

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for(var i=0, n=a.length; i<n; i++)
{
  a[i].src = 'images/'+a[i].src; //see note
}
```

note: in practice I think you'll want a regex replace to insert the 'images/' string here

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("img").attr("src", function (val) {
          return "images/" + val;
        })
```

Comment: yeah that'd be it :) one of these days I'll have to start caring about jquery